# What is the best way to set up inheritance to avoid future redundancy in code?

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have 7 classes:

```
public class Entity
{
   public int Id { get; set; }     
}

public class Product : ????
{
    // Contructor
    public Product()
    {
        Photos = new HashSet<PhotoSource>();
        ProductFeatures = new HashSet<ProductFeature>();
    }

    // Primitives
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public string InternalSKU { get; set; }
    public string ModelNumber { get; set; } 
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int QtyPerUnit { get; set; }
    public double UnitPrice { get; set; }
    public int UnitsInStock { get; set; }
    public int UnitsOnOrder { get; set; }
    public int? ReOrderLevel { get; set; }
    public string Warranty { get; set; }

    // Foreign Keys
    public int SubCategoryID { get; set; }
    public int VendorId { get; set; }

    // Navigation Properties
    // Classes
    [ForeignKey("SubCategoryID")]
    public virtual SubCategory SubCategory { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("VendorId")]
    public virtual Vendor Vendor { get; set; }

    // Collections
    public virtual ICollection<PhotoSource> Photos { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ProductFeature> ProductFeatures { get; set; }
}


public class ProductSeasonal : ????
{
    // Primitives
    public int? OffSeasonDiscount { get; set; }
    public DateTime SeasonStartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime SeasonEndDate { get; set; }
    public int? QtyLimitedTo { get; set; }
}

public class ProductDiscontinued : ????
{
    // Primitives
    public DateTime DiscontinuedDate { get; set; }
    public int DiscontinuedDisount { get; set; }
}

public class Supply : ????
{
    // Primitives
    public String UnitMeasurement { get; set; }
}

public class Part : ????
{
    // Primitives
    public String UnitMeasurement { get; set; }
}

 public class Vehicle : ????
{
    // Constructor
    public Vehicle()
    {
        ExteriorFeatures = new HashSet<ProductFeature>();
        InteriorFeatures = new HashSet<ProductFeature>();
        SafetyFeatures = new HashSet<ProductFeature>();
    }

    // Primitives
    public string VIN { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public int CylinderSize { get; set; }
    public double EngineSize { get; set; }
    public string StyleType { get; set; } //Truck, SUV, Sedan, Convertible, etc
    public string TransmissionType { get; set; }
    public string InteriorColor { get; set; } 
    public string ExteriorColor { get; set; }

    // Foreign Keys
    public virtual int MakeId { get; set; }


    // Navigation Properties
    // Classes
    [ForeignKey("MakeId")]
    public virtual VehicleMake Make { get; set; }

    // Collections
    public virtual ICollection<ProductFeature> InteriorFeatures { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ProductFeature> ExteriorFeatures { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ProductFeature> SafetyFeatures { get; set; }
}
```

What would be the best way to set up inheritance so Vehicle, Parts, Supplies and any future sale item class [eg. clothing] can be added with not much fuss with redundant properties being coded?

Comment: I know Vehicle, Supply, and Part would probably inherit from Product, but how do I work out the inheritance between Product, Discontinued and Seasonal? And who inherits from Entity?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to start is to write down all of the properties for each item of interest currently.

So, any product will have a price and some unique id (sku number) and maybe a barcode and an image.

So, these could be the start of some parent class.

As you go through other products you may find commonalities.

If you need to start selling jeans, then look at what other clothing may be needed, as you may want to have material or style be listed.

But, don't try to design your classes so that they will able to handle anything.

Design for what you have right now, but make it flexible enough so you can add new properties if you need to.  For example, right now I wouldn't add a qrcode image, but later it may be common enough to be added.

Is your question actually for class design or, ultimately, for database design?

Answer (score 1):

I decided to combined Seasonal & Discontinued into Product and have Product inherit from Entity.
Many thanks to the Comments/Word police. I did not realize we had more editors on this site than answer helpers. So, this is how I will proceed:

```
     public Product()
    {
        OrderDetails = new HashSet<OrderDetail>();
        Photos = new HashSet<PhotoSource>();
        ProductFeatures = new HashSet<ProductFeature>();
    }

    // Primitives
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public string InternalSKU { get; set; }
    public string ModelNumber { get; set; } 
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int QtyPerUnit { get; set; }
    public double UnitPrice { get; set; }
    public int UnitsInStock { get; set; }
    public int UnitsOnOrder { get; set; }
    public int? ReOrderLevel { get; set; }
    public string Warranty { get; set; }
    // Primitives for Disontinues
    public DateTime? DiscontinuedDate { get; set; }
    public int? DiscontinuedDisount { get; set; }
    // Primitives for Seasonal
    public int? OffSeasonDiscount { get; set; }
    public DateTime? SeasonStartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? SeasonEndDate { get; set; }
    public int? QtyLimitedTo { get; set; }


    // Foreign Keys
    public int SubCategoryID { get; set; }
    public int VendorId { get; set; }

    // Navigation Properties
    // Classes
    [ForeignKey("SubCategoryID")]
    public virtual SubCategory SubCategory { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("VendorId")]
    public virtual Vendor Vendor { get; set; }

    // Collections
    public ICollection<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PhotoSource> Photos { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ProductFeature> ProductFeatures { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some times "has a relationship" (composition) are easier to maintain than  "is a relationship"(inheritance) as the application grows. Looks like this is one of those scenarios. You can set it up so that each of the entities has a product class. And you can use inversion of control to inject product into these entities.

This link explains the rationale in this article.

http://www.artima.com/designtechniques/compoinh4.html